# cassandra gc grace period cannot configure

Tags: cassandra, datastax

with ref to "https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/tabProp.html"
I need to configure gc grace period as a solution for tombstones while deletion.

But I am getting below error while restarting .

```
"com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors: 1) An exception was caught and reported. Message: Invalid yaml. Please remove properties [gc_grace_seconds] from your cassandra.yaml
  at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.configure(Unknown Source)
"

cqlsh> show VERSION
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.0.1855 | DSE 5.1.3 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
```

Answer (score 5):

you can alter your table after connecting to cqlsh by default the value of gc_grace_period is 10 days.

Connect to clqsh
cqlsh  
cqlsh> alter keyspace.table_name with gc_grace_seconds = 864000 ;

Note :10 days = 864000 seconds

Comment: The correct command is alter table keyspace.table_name with gc_grace_seconds = 864000 ;  (i think you missed table)

Comment: It's there. You see "keyspace.table_name".

Answer (score 3):

Anushke, this is set at the schema level, not in cassandra.yaml.

Answer (score 2):

`gc_grace_seconds` is defined as a part of each table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE testTable (
    testid bigint,
    vendid bigint,
    updatets timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (testid, vendid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (vendid ASC)
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000;
```

By default it is set to 864000 (ten days).

And I do have to caution you about adjusting that setting.  Remember that tombstones are Cassandra's way of replicating "nothing."  That's really hard to do in distributed databases, hence the reason for the tombstone structure.  Just be sure that you are running a repair within the range of your new value, otherwise your tombstones may not do their job (replicate nothing out to all your nodes) and you could have data "ghosting" its way back.

Comment: If i didn't set value for this setting table by table  , is it taking "gc_grace_seconds" as 864000   ? i need to handle below describe  quoted scenario....

Comment: "If a node receives a delete for data it inlocally, the node tombstones the specified record and tries to pass the tombstone to others containing replicas of that record. But if one replica node is unresponsive , it does not receive the tombstone immediately, so it still contains the pre-delete version of the record. If the tombstoned record has already been deleted from the rest of the cluster befor that node recovers, Cassandra treats the record on the recovered node as new data, and propagates it to the rest of the cluster. This kind of deleted but persistent record is called a zombie."

Comment: Yes, the default is 864000 seconds.  Pretty much any reasonable time period will cover your “zombie” scenario, as long as you can run repair within that time.